# iPad Hardware Keyboard Shortcuts in Split View

Tags: ipad, keyboard, shortcut

For reference, I'm using the iPad Pro 2018 model.

I've run into some pretty frustrating behavior with iPadOS and a hardware keyboard, and I wanted to ask for help here.

How do you **swap between apps in Split View**?  `Cmd + Tab` works fine when switching between apps when they're just open by themselves, but let's say I have Safari and Youtube open side-by-side. In that case, `Cmd + Tab` stops working and I'm unable to swap back and forth between each split.

Am I missing something really obvious here, or is there really no way to do that via hardware keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: AD works better with only one question per post, I‘ve edited your post accordingly.

Comment: Having said that, at least according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205237 there is no Cmd-Q on iPads.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?